Multiple Disparate URL Redirect Using IIS Rewrite
I have a strange scenario where we are having to decommission an old training environment that was home grown.  The problem being we have over 6,000 URLs that need redirecting/rewriting to disparate systems in our environment.  As an example:
Training courses will need redirecting from https://rxtraining.domain.com/training/course.php?courseid=42654 to a whole new structure at https://techarea.domain.com/xyz/abc/coursework/course.php?courseid=123456.
Additionally, those courses have various assets associated with them that will need redirecting/rewriting from https://rxtraining.domain.com/training/assets/asset1.php?assetid=45678 to https://domain.sharepoint.com/sitepages/asset40521.aspx.
All of this to say, because there is no correlated pattern, it would be easier to just have a straight map table where we lookup the old URL and provide the new URL.  I've worked through the examples here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-custom-rewrite-providers-with-url-rewrite-module.  I can't get the database example to even perform a query, so have tried the FileMapProvider, which has given more success but am getting a 500.50 error message.
My rule is the following:
<rule name="FileMapProvider" stopProcessing=true>
<match url="(.*)" />
<conditions>
    <add input="{FileMap:{R:0}}" pattern="(.+)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="{C:0}" />
</rule>

Am I even close?

So, you cannot use the simplest rewrite map? https://learn.microsoft.com/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module

It appears what I'm trying to do is unsupported after a long search session.  You can't use the rewrite map in a separate file or DB, so I'd have to manage over 6,000 entries in the web.config file.  The size and number of the URLs would likely push me over the 250k limit and impact performance.

What I was attempting to do is not supported.  To use static rewrite maps, you have to do it inside the web.config file.  Managing over 6,000 static maps in web.config doesn't seem tenable, so I will have to look elsewhere.

"you have to do it inside the web.config file" is wrong, and IIS Product Manager explained that more than a decade ago, https://ruslany.net/2010/05/storing-url-rewrite-mappings-in-a-separate-file/

All the MS docs say static maps are required to be in web.config.  This seems backwards, but I’m just going on their docs.
